# Remove hover legend from bar chart using morris.js

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, morris.js

I'm using [morris.js library](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/) to generate charts.

I want to remove the hover legends from the chart. Please check the picture below for better understanding. How can I remove them? Any idea to fix it? Thanks in advance.

[image: example chart showing what to remove]

```js
new Morris.Bar({
  // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
  element: 'myfirstchart',
  // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
  // the chart.
  data: [
    {year: '2008', value: 20},
    {year: '2009', value: 10},
    {year: '2010', value: 5},
    {year: '2011', value: 5},
    {year: '2012', value: 20}
  ],
  // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
  xkey: 'year',
  // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
  ykeys: ['value'],
  // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
  // chart.
  labels: ['Value']
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the hover legend, use the `hideHover` property and set it to `'always'`.

The `hideHover` property accepts the following values:

- `false` (boolean) - always show a hover legend
- `true` (boolean) or `'auto'` (string) - only show the hover legend, when the mouse cursor is over the chart
- `'always'` (string) - never show a hover legend

```js
new Morris.Bar({
  // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
  element: 'myfirstchart',
  // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
  // the chart.
  data: [
    {year: '2008', value: 20},
    {year: '2009', value: 10},
    {year: '2010', value: 5},
    {year: '2011', value: 5},
    {year: '2012', value: 20}
  ],
  // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
  xkey: 'year',
  // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
  ykeys: ['value'],
  // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
  // chart.
  labels: ['Value'],
  // Remove hover legend
  hideHover: 'always'
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
```

You can also **customize the hover legend** by assigning a `callback` function to the `hoverCallback` property:

```js
new Morris.Bar({
  // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
  element: 'myfirstchart',
  // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
  // the chart.
  data: [
    {year: '2008', value: 20},
    {year: '2009', value: 10},
    {year: '2010', value: 5},
    {year: '2011', value: 5},
    {year: '2012', value: 20}
  ],
  // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
  xkey: 'year',
  // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
  ykeys: ['value'],
  // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
  // chart.
  labels: ['Value'],
  // Customized hover legend via a callback
  hoverCallback: function (index, options, content, row) {
    return 'Legend ' + index + '<br> on year ' + row.year + '<br> with value ' + row.value;
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
```

[**Check out the morris.js API for line & area charts**](https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html)